# SQL Server 2016 Live Query Statistics greyed out

Tags: sql-server, database-administration, sql-server-2016

Regardless of the type of query I'm running, the *Include Live Query Statistics* option is always greyed out.

Any idea how I can enable this?

[image]

Comment: What is compatibility level for that database?

Comment: What is output of `SELECT @@VERSION` ?

Comment: @BogdanSahlean SELECT @@VERSION gives Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP2-GDR). However, Help > About gives Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 13.0.16106.4

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Q:

> What is output of SELECT @@VERSION ?

A:

> SELECT @@VERSION gives Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP2-GDR). However,
>   Help > About gives Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 13.0.16106.4

In this case, SQL Server Management Studio 2016 is used to connect to SQL Server 2012 Database Engine instance. The minimum `Database Engine` version for `Live Query` is SQL 2014 SP1.

Reference: http://blogs.lobsterpot.com.au/2015/08/31/live-query-statistics-in-sql-2014-not-just-sql-2016/